# Debugging .svelte files in chrome

Tags: svelte

Previously when debugging .svelte files I would have formatted code viewable in Chrome debugger that I could debug with breakpoints. Something has changed recently and not sure what happened but I can no longer see my code formatted, it appears as plain text. What's more, when I put a breakpoint, the breakpoint is hit, but I can't mouse over any of the variables. If I type the variable name in the console it's fine and I can then mouseover the variable to see its contents, but this is a pain when trying to debug. Is anyone else experiencing this?

[image: Debugging in Chrome doesn't format my typescript code]

Comment: If you are generating source-maps and attaching via VSCode, breakpoints work just fine for me. Especially using sveltekit, everything just kinda works with VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

The [Svelte browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svelte-devtools/kfidecgcdjjfpeckbblhmfkhmlgecoff) has real-time component prop inspection and more, which may help to solve some of your problems. I’m not sure about it’s debugging capabilities, however.